# Get OAUTH 2 token from Dropbox using SDK

Tags: ios, dropbox

Is there any way to get the oauth 2 token from the ios dropbox sdk? Generally the token received is oauth 1 token but I need that oauth 2 token.

Please help me

Thanks in advance..

Comment: if you are using latest dropbox iOS SDK then it would return you `oAuth1` only. For more details refer [document here](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/core/start/ios)

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I have noticed that. But need that badly. So, searching a way... :(

Comment: Then you need to you use webSDK for it. it uses oAuth2.

Comment: Even some of the SDKs are using oAuth2 with iOS, you can check more details [here](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/reference/oauthguide), refer `Setting up your app` section, it mentions clearly. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

If you have an OAuth 1 token, you can convert it to an OAuth 2 token via the [/token_from_oauth1](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/core/docs#oa2-from-oa1) endpoint.

See also https://blogs.dropbox.com/developers/2014/03/upgrading-a-dropbox-oauth-1-token-to-oauth-2/.