# Dropbox - Migrating oauth1 to oauth2 using token_from_oauth1

Tags: c#, oauth, dropbox

I have been using Dropbox via the Sharpbox toolkit for a while.  It's based on oAuth1, so I have a database full of oAuth1 access tokens for my users.

I'd like to convert to the new Dropbox API, which is based on oAuth2.  I see that there is a "token_from_oauth1" endpoint in Dropbox's v1 spec (reference [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30504591/get-oauth-2-token-from-dropbox-using-sdk/30508935#30508935)), but I'm not figuring out how to successfully connect to this endpoint to upgrade a user's existing token.  (I'm using C#/.NET).

Can anybody point me to some sample code that shows how to create a properly authenticated call to perform this operation?  I think the problem is in trying to correctly authenticate/sign the request.  (All of my existing dropbox calls are done by the Sharpbox library, so I can't see how it does the authentication).

Thanks!

Comment: [Cross-linking for reference: https://www.dropboxforum.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/204375656-Migrating-oauth1-to-oauth2-using-token-from-oauth1- ]

Answer (score -1, accepted):

There's a library for Twitter oAuth 1.0 (see http://www.voiceoftech.com/swhitley/?p=681) that actually makes it easy to make oAuth 1.0 authenticated calls.  So the code below seems to work pretty well for me:

```
oAuthTwitter oat = new oAuthTwitter();
oat.Token = <oauth 1.0 token>;
oat.TokenSecret = <oauth 1.0 secret>;
oat.ConsumerKey = <application key>;
oat.ConsumerSecret = <application secret>;
string resultJSON = oat.oAuthWebRequest(oAuthTwitter.Method.POST, "https://api.dropboxapi.com/1/oauth2/token_from_oauth1", null);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get this using a simple rest client (Like RestSharp) and doing a call like this

I'm currently doing this in a xamarin app, i use the xamarin dropbox core api to login, and get the oauth_token, oauth_consumer_key and the oauth_signature. If you managed the oauth1 flow with c# is then easy to get the oauth2 token.

```
            var rclient = new RestSharp.RestClient("https://api.dropboxapi.com/1/");
            var rrequest = new RestSharp.RestRequest("oauth2/token_from_oauth1", Method.POST);
            rrequest.AddHeader("Authorization", "OAuth oauth_version=\"1.0\", oauth_signature_method=\"PLAINTEXT\"");

            rrequest.AddParameter("oauth_consumer_key", store.GetConsumerKey());
            rrequest.AddParameter("oauth_token", store.GetAccessToken());
            rrequest.AddParameter("oauth_signature", String.Concat(App.DropboxAppSecret, "&", store.GetAccessTokenSecret()));

            var rresponse = rclient.Execute(rrequest);
            string content = rresponse.Content;
```